# How to bundle polkadot.js with rollup?

Tags: polkadot-js

I'm trying to build a single js file application with polakdot.js by using rollup to bundle everything together, but some of the polakdot.js libraries can't be resolved by the rollup node resolve plugin.

```
@polkadot/x-randomvalues (imported by @polkadot/x-randomvalues?commonjs-external)
@polkadot/x-textdecoder (imported by @polkadot/x-textdecoder?commonjs-external)
@polkadot/x-textencoder (imported by @polkadot/x-textencoder?commonjs-external)
@polkadot/x-fetch (imported by @polkadot/x-fetch?commonjs-external)
```

Is there some extra configuration that polkadot.js requires to bundle?

Answer (score 2):

Browser bundles for the various packages are available in the [polkadot-js GH org](https://github.com/polkadot-js/build-bundle) and also as part of the npm packages. These are indeed all built with rollup.

First off, not a bundling guru, so take this with a grain of salt.

My guess at your issue: all the `x-*` packages use export maps extensively, so  it needs quite a recent version of the rollup node resolver to work - older version and known to have issues. So my first suggestion would be to ensure that -resolve and -commonjs are on the latest plugin versions, alongside rollup.

As to how polkadot-js bundles - it is not that easy to untangle, since it uses some scripts that are [shared between the various repos](https://github.com/polkadot-js/dev/blob/master/packages/dev/config/rollup.js) the relevant bit there would be for the plugins added -

```
    plugins: [
      pluginAlias({ entries }),
      pluginJson(),
      pluginCommonjs(),
      pluginInject(inject),
      pluginResolve({ browser: true }),
      pluginCleanup()
    ]
```

Apart from some [overrides for some packages](https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/5c92e095ffc1f7f92dfaedbde72d50b027fb18e5/rollup.config.mjs#L27) there are no specific/additional build steps applied for the various packages, the above shared config applies to all.

Comment: Sorry for lacking background here, I was trying to build for nodejs, if I exclude these dependencies, they will not be bundled into the result file.

Comment: The above answer doesn't mean to exclude anything - rather it seems to focus on the actual rollup versions. From my reading, specifically the x-* packages, which is confirmed by the source, needs to be includes, but it requires new node resolution in rollup.